# How To Animate Apple-Style CSS3 Keyframes?

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I recently published a question about building [this Mac product browser animation](http://www.apple.com/mac/) using jQuery. This seems to work fine, however some users went into the source code and found that Apple is using CSS3 animations with keyframes. I have looked over the source and I'm struggling to get this working. I would love any help if somebody can take a peek.

[image: Apple page animation]

Please note I am **not** interested in the bottom sliding panel links - only the first animation which happens when you initially load the page. All the items will bounce like elastic from out-of-view into the product browser. The codes are found inside this page document: http://images.apple.com/global/styles/productbrowser.css

Specifically lines 169-340 showcase the keyframe animations. I will copy over a chunk of the code in hopes that somebody will recognize the syntax. Thanks in advance for any help I truly appreciate it.

```
/* open browser animation */
.productbrowser.pb-dynamic ul:first-child li                 a { opacity:0; }
.productbrowser.pb-open    ul:first-child li                 a { opacity:1; -webkit-animation-duration:.8s; -moz-animation-duration:.8s; -o-animation-duration:.8s; animation-duration:.8s; }
.productbrowser.pb-open    ul:first-child li:nth-child(1)    a { -webkit-animation-name:open-1; -moz-animation-name:open-1; -o-animation-name:open-1; animation-name:open-1; }
.productbrowser.pb-open    ul:first-child li:nth-child(2)    a { -webkit-animation-name:open-2; -moz-animation-name:open-2; -o-animation-name:open-2; animation-name:open-2; }
.productbrowser.pb-open    ul:first-child li:nth-child(3)    a { -webkit-animation-name:open-3; -moz-animation-name:open-3; -o-animation-name:open-3; animation-name:open-3; }
.productbrowser.pb-open    ul:first-child li:nth-child(4)    a { -webkit-animation-name:open-4; -moz-animation-name:open-4; -o-animation-name:open-4; animation-name:open-4; }
.productbrowser.pb-open    ul:first-child li:nth-child(5)    a { -webkit-animation-name:open-5; -moz-animation-name:open-5; -o-animation-name:open-5; animation-name:open-5; }
.productbrowser.pb-open    ul:first-child li:nth-child(6)    a { -webkit-animation-name:open-6; -moz-animation-name:open-6; -o-animation-name:open-6; animation-name:open-6; }
.productbrowser.pb-open    ul:first-child li:nth-child(7)    a { -webkit-animation-name:open-7; -moz-animation-name:open-7; -o-animation-name:open-7; animation-name:open-7; }
.productbrowser.pb-open    ul:first-child li:nth-child(8)    a { -webkit-animation-name:open-8; -moz-animation-name:open-8; -o-animation-name:open-8; animation-name:open-8; }
.productbrowser.pb-open    ul:first-child li:nth-child(9)    a { -webkit-animation-name:open-8; -moz-animation-name:open-8; -o-animation-name:open-8; animation-name:open-8; }
.productbrowser.pb-opened  ul:first-child li                 a { opacity:1; }

/* keyframes
------------------------*/

/* open browser keyframes */

@-webkit-keyframes open-1 {
    from { opacity:0; -webkit-transform:translate3d( 210px, -145px, 0); }
    25%  { opacity:1; -webkit-transform:translate3d( -15.6px, 4.1px, 0); }
    30%  { opacity:1; -webkit-transform:translate3d( -10.3px, 2.7px, 0); }
    35%  { opacity:1; -webkit-transform:translate3d( 0, 0, 0); }
    40%  { opacity:1; -webkit-transform:translate3d( 4.5px, -1.2px, 0); }
    45%  { opacity:1; -webkit-transform:translate3d( 2.9px, -0.8px, 0); }
    50%  { opacity:1; -webkit-transform:translate3d( 0, 0, 0); }
    55%  { opacity:1; -webkit-transform:translate3d( -1.3px, 0.3px, 0); }
    60%  { opacity:1; -webkit-transform:translate3d( -0.8px, 0.2px, 0); }
    65%  { opacity:1; -webkit-transform:translate3d( 0, 0, 0); }
    70%  { opacity:1; -webkit-transform:translate3d( 0.4px, -0.1px, 0); }
    75%  { opacity:1; -webkit-transform:translate3d( 0.2px, -0.1px, 0); }
    80%  { opacity:1; -webkit-transform:translate3d( 0, 0, 0); }
    85%  { opacity:1; -webkit-transform:translate3d( -0.1px, 0, 0); }
    90%  { opacity:1; -webkit-transform:translate3d( -0.1px, 0, 0); }
    to   { opacity:1; -webkit-transform:translate3d( 0, 0, 0); }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a pretty simple css syntax. you target an element

```
.productbrowser.pb-open    ul:first-child li:nth-child(4)    a {animation-name:open-4; }
```

Here you are targeting an  element that is the 4 child in a li that is the first child in a ul that is a descendant of an element with classes productbrowser and pb-open. To this element, you assign the animation open-4 (I have omitted vendor prefixes).

the animation duration is given generically for all the elements.

then the animation distributes the given time in percentages,

```
@-webkit-keyframes open-1 {
    from { opacity:0; -webkit-transform:translate3d( 210px, -145px, 0); }
    25%  { opacity:1; -webkit-transform:translate3d( -15.6px, 4.1px, 0); }
    30%  { opacity:1; -webkit-transform:translate3d( -10.3px, 2.7px, 0); }
    35%  { opacity:1; -webkit-transform:translate3d( 0, 0, 0); }
```

From the first step, opacity is set to 1, and then tghe remaining step are only movements. it is really a 2 d movement, the z coordinates are always 0

Comment: Thanks for providing a response I will have to setup a jsfiddle later and see how it works. appreciate the quick explanation because keyframes have been a struggle in my studies.